# How to improve VHF/UHF Baofeng UV-82 HT reception in vehicle

Tags: antenna, ht, mobile, vhf, uhf

I have a Baofeng UV-82 dual-band (2m/70cm) HT with an SMA male connector for the stock "rubber-ducky" antenna. I would like to use it in my vehicle. I would like a high-quality magnetic mount dual-band antenna for the roof of my vehicle (so that I can easily move it between two vehicles). I intend to use the [Wouxoun WXUHF adapter](http://www.hamradio.com/detail.cfm?pid=H0-011738) with the [Tram BR-354 magnetic mount](http://www.hamradio.com/detail.cfm?pid=H0-009826) to connect to the antenna. I am specifically considering the following model and any comparable (or better) models:

- [Comet-NCG SBB-5](http://www.hamradio.com/detail.cfm?pid=H0-001570)
- A comparable Diamond-brand antenna (recommendations welcome)
- Any other comparable/better antenna that would work well

Will this model perform optimally for my circumstances and equipment? Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of? Are there any better/comparable brands/models I should also look at? Are the adapter and magnetic mount I chose good for this or do you have other recommendations?

Answer (score 5):

Any reputable mag mount antenna will be a huge gain compared to the rubber ducky. I routinely can hit mid-level repeaters from about 15 miles away with my mag mount setup and 5W. If I'm extremely careful, I can hit the same repeaters from 5 miles away with the rubber ducky antenna, in order to pull that off, I have to hold the HT perfectly straight.

One thing to keep in mind is get a short cable. Measure what your needs are, and maybe get a few more feet, not more. Also, it's usually best to get a small adapter cable, such as [this one](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B007PPHUO2/ref=as_li_ss_til?tag=httpwwwpearso-20&camp=0&creative=0&linkCode=as4&creativeASIN=B007PPHUO2&adid=1Y8BRWY7PMJYDBF646CX&). And good luck!

Comment: Do you have any other antenna recommendations (specific brand/model)?

Answer (score 3):

A [magnetic mount antenna](http://www.gigaparts.com/Product-Lines/Magnet-Mounts/MFJ-332S.html), or a permanent antenna mount (like a roof rack or trunk lip mount) will definitely help you out.  The point is to get the antenna out of the car!

In a pinch, consider [this window-clip mount](http://www.gigaparts.com/Product-Lines/Window-License-Plate/MFJ-310S.html) that you attach your hand-held antenna directly to.

[Actually, just putting it near the windshield will help at least a little bit.]

(I am in no way shape or form recommending gigaparts or MFJ as better than other options; they're both excellent but so are most of their alternatives.  They were just who I linked to at the moment)

Answer (score 2):

I currently use an MFJ mag mount, but as previously suggested, any antenna that goes on the outside of the car is better than one on the inside.

If you're not shy about putting holes in your car, an antenna physically attached to the car may provide an improved RF ground plane for a little more gain.

Using an SMA adapter cable for your radio rather than an SMA adapter will reduce the strain on the HT connector and keep it from breaking

Answer (score 1):

Mag mounts really aren't all they're cracked up to be. You'll see some improvement just because the antenna is outside of the car, but a through-roof mount gives you a good ground connection and no risk of tossing your antenna into another car while on the highway.

I know the common argument. Yeah, you need to drill a hole, but that's in many ways less damaging than using a mag mount which can scrape your paint every time it moves. At least it's easy to plug the hole if you ever need to sell the car.

Comment: The problem is that I need to move it between two vehicles regularly, so a mag-mount is still my best option.

Comment: I'd almost rather do two through-roof installs - but to each his own I guess